# Boolean variable is automatically changing its value

Tags: c++, algorithm

This problem is from SPOJ. I was required to find whether the graph is Bi-partite or not. I'm using BFS to find it. 
The problem here is in a while loop under the section `//PROBLEM COMING HERE` (please see the code under to find this statement.)

Problem description:

I want to toggle between 0 and 1. So I have chosen a `bool` value called `flag` and initialised it with 0. Now, per iteration I want to toggle it's value. So I have used `flag = !flag`. However, for some unknown reasons the flag value automatically toggles after the first iteration before executing the statement `flag = ! flag`. 
So, because of this lot of problems are coming.

```
//BUG LIFE
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

#define DEFAULT 2
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t,n,e;
    bool eflag;
    //freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    //Taking the Testcase
    scanf("%d",&t);
    //Iterating each Testcase
    for(int itr=1; itr<=t; itr++)
    {
        //n is the number of nodes in the graph and e is the no of edges.
        scanf("%d %d",&n,&e);
        //eflag is exit flag in short. this is used to early exit to save time if we already found out that the given graph isn't bi-partite.
        //Assuming the graph is bi-partite hence eflag = false meaning no exit is required yet.
        eflag = false;
        //Graph data structure vector 2D Array
        vector < vector < int > > graph(n+1);
        //Taking edges as input and adding in the graph
        for(int i = 1; i <=e; i++)
        {
            int v1,v2;
            scanf("%d %d",&v1,&v2);
            graph[v1].push_back(v2);
            graph[v2].push_back(v1);
        }
        //Check the graph is bi-partite or not
        //vis is an array which will hold whether a node has been explored or not. label is an array which segregates all the nodes in two groups 0 or 1. 
        bool vis[n+1]; int label[n+1];
        //Initialising vis and label.

        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            vis[i] = 0;
            //DEFALUT VALUE IS 2. This is to tell that label of the node i hasn't been given yet or in otherwords, it's not be put in a group yet.
            label[i] = DEFAULT;
        }
        //Taking nodes one by one and doing a BFS on it.
        //LOGIC Here is: Take a node assign it a label 0 and add all the children of it in the queue and give them label 1. Now explore all children and give their children label 0. So like this, we alternate between labels. 
//Now if we see that a node already has a label apart from 2 and a children is trying to label it with something different label it will mean that specific node is involved in both the groups. Hence we will set the eflag as true.
        for(int i=1; i<=n && !eflag; i++)
        {
            if(!graph[i].empty() && !vis[i])
            {
                //Initialising the queue and adding the first node which has children.
                queue <int> q;
                q.push(i); bool flag;
                //PROBLEM COMING HERE
                //Assigning the label for this node as 0. meaning group 0
                label[i] = 0; flag = false;
                //BFS Starts
                while(!q.empty() && !eflag)
                {
                    int x = q.front();  q.pop();
                    printf("%d **\n",flag);
                    //The children of this node needs to have different label than parent. Hence flag = !flag
                    flag = !flag;
                    printf("%d %d\n",x,flag);
                    if(vis[x]) continue;
                    vis[x] = 1;
                    //Exploring the children and assigning them labels
                    for(vector <int>::iterator it = graph[x].begin(); it != graph[x].end(); it++)
                    {
                        //If the children doesn't have a default label and the label which it has is different than the one the parent is trying to put then it means that this child belongs to both the groups 0 and 1. So exit.
                        if(label[*it] != DEFAULT && label[*it] != flag)
                        {
                            printf("%d %d %d %d\n",x,*it,label[*it],flag);
                            eflag = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            label[*it] = flag;
                        }
                    }
                    printf("asd %d **\n",flag);
                }
                //PROBLEM ENDS HERE
            }
        }
        if(eflag == false)
            printf("Scenario #%d:\nNo suspicious bugs found!\n",itr);
        else
            printf("Scenario #%d:\nSuspicious bugs found!\n",itr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
0 **
1 1 
asd 1 ** 
0 ** 
2 1 
2 1 0 1 
asd 1 ** 
Scenario #1: 
Suspicious bugs found!
```

Sample Input:

```
1
3 3
1 2
2 3
1 3
```

Comment: Why some-one downvoted this? Is there any reason for it?

Comment: Did you notice you have two loops?

Comment: @TagirValeev: Sure. I'll do that.

Comment: @stark: Yes, I know but how is it relevant?

Comment: Reduce your code to a mcve.

Comment: How about using meaningful variable names instead of `t`, `n`, `e`?

Comment: Where does your output show the problem? You initialized `flag` to false, and the first line of output has `0 **`, which is false.

Comment: @Barmar: After it prints asd 1** it should print again 1 ** because flag = ! flag hasn't been executed yet. However it shows 0 **

Comment: The code doesn't even compile....

Comment: @SimonKraemer: Did you created the input file? Notice the freopen() statement in the code.

Comment: @user3811219 If it doesn't compile, the input file is irrelevant.

Comment: I said "it doesn't compile", not "it doesn't run". Yes I did create the input file.
This line doesn't work `bool vis[n+1]; int label[n+1];` as `n` isn't constant. I'm working around it, but you should adjust your example.

Comment: @user3811219 C++ doesn't have variable-length arrays, but maybe some implementations add it as an extension.

Comment: Next problem: `if (label[*it] != DEFAULT && label[*it] != flag)`... `label[*it]`is of type `int` flag is `bool`. Did you mean to write `if (label[*it] != DEFAULT && vis[*it] != flag)`?

Comment: If a variable is being changed spotaneously, it's most likely due to referencing outside an array bound in another assignment.

Comment: @SimonKraemer: No I meant that only. `code` if (label[*it] != DEFAULT && label[*it] != flag)

Comment: You should also check the return values of `freopen` and `scanf`

Comment: @user3811219 So you want to check that `if(5 != 2 && 5 != true)`??? Please explain. This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Can someone please explain why the behaviour is like this with details and secondly, why so many down-vote? :(

Comment: @user3811219 First let me explain the downvotes: 1) Your code doesn't compile. 2) You are doing strange things in there. 3) No one knows what you expect the code to do.

Comment: 4) It is too much code. You already have been told to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @user3811219 To get an answer and no downvotes: 1) Add a compilable example. 2) Explain why you do stuff the way you do it if someone asks. 3) Provide an example input and an expected output.

Comment: @SimonKraemer: Label[*it] can't be 5. It can be 0,1 and 2. This was needed because I'm seperating all the nodes in two parts 0 and 1. Hence nodes havving the label 0 are in one group and nodes having label 1 are in another. 
I'm taking the value DEFAULT (2) so as to know if the node has been labelled or not.

Comment: @user3811219 It doesn't matter that it can only be 0,1 and 2. Comparing `2==true` or `1==false` does work but doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: The code does compile. I'd suggest to remove the freopen statement and try to compile again. Maybe it's the compiler problem. I'm using C++ 4.3.2. 

@BaummitAugen: I'm reading the page. please give me sometime to understand it and reflect it on the post.

Comment: @user3811219 there is no "C++ 4.3.2". You probably meant g++, which is a c++ compiler. No, it does not compile (as standard c++)... hint: you're using non-standard language feature that is not part of c++ (already mentioned by Barmar). If you do such a thing, you must mention it in the question (and mention the compiler which supports the feature) so that we are aware of it. Removing the input code is a good start for your mcve.

Comment: @user3811219 Yes, but only as `Variable-length automatic arrays are allowed in ISO C99, and as an extension GCC accepts them in C90 mode and in C++.`

Comment: @SimonKraemer: `label[*it] != DEFAULT && label[*it] != flag` 
i agree label is an integer and flag is boolean and comparing them make no sense but if you see the way conditions are evaluated in a "&&" statement. It sees the first condition and sees if it's true or not. Only and Only when it's true it moves to the second condition. 
So, label will always have the value 0 or 1 in the second condition.

Comment: **Just compiled and ran it on ideone. I'll suggest you to use that ** http://ideone.com/MdUMlU

Comment: @user3811219: Ok. That's all I wanted to know in the first place. You could make this clear by writing `(label[*it] != DEFAULT && (label[*it]!=0) != flag)` and/or adding a comment.

Comment: Hint: print something each time you enter the surrounding for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption in the comment:

> After it prints asd 1** it should print again 1 ** because flag = ! flag hasn't been executed yet. However it shows 0 **

Is wrong. (Not the assumption that `flag = ! flag` hasn't been executed, that's correct.)

In the following snippet, I've cut most of the irrelevant code away (you're welcome). Let's name some of your loops:

```
for(int i=1; i<=n && !eflag; i++) // outer loop
{
    // ..
        queue <int> q;
        q.push(i); bool flag;
        label[i] = 0; flag = false; // (1)
        while(!q.empty() && !eflag) // inner loop
        {
            int x = q.front();  q.pop();
            printf("%d **\n",flag); // (2)
            flag = !flag;
            printf("%d %d\n",x,flag);
            // ...
            printf("asd %d **\n",flag); // (3)
        }
    // ...
}
```

You only ever push exactly one element into `q`. That's at the top of outer loop. You always pop it at the top of inner loop. Inner loops condition is true only if the queue is not empty. Therefore the inner loop always runs at most once per outer loop. Because the inner loop is never repeated more than once, you always jump to the beginning of the outer loop after printing `asd 1**` at the end of inner loop (3). At the top of outer loop (1), you assign `flag = false`. Therefore, regardless of the value of `flag` when it's printed at (3), it's value will always be `false` at (2).

As you can see, the variable isn't changing "automatically" or because of "unknown reasons". It's changing because you assign it at (1).

Comment: First of all, Thanks a lot ! :) 
I forgot to push the childrens :( :( I'm so so embarassed. However, I learn't a lot of things in order how to format, edit the code. thanks a lot everyone. :)
Works like a charm after adding the children :)